# Jenkins processes

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, process

Is it normal to have that many processes active for Jenkins?
I checked my settings, I only have 2 "executors" configured...

[htop http://d.pr/i/RZzG+](http://d.pr/i/RZzG+)

Comment: Please more details!

Comment: @juanmajmjr oops sorry - here is the screen capture

Answer (score 0):

You have not only to limit the executors in the Master,  but also in the nodes.  In Manage Nodes inside the configuration of Jenkins you can change the # of executors for nodes.

Comment: Sorry but I checked that conf as well and it is capped by the main setting of Master... So I don't think this really answers the problem here

Comment: Ok, but remember you should check always before accepting an answer. Opposite is not making sense.